# How to run Jenkins build as any user

Tags: python, testing, jenkins, automation, server

I have a jenkins server that can ssh into several other servers and run `foo.py`the script makes a result directory based on the user. Multiple people can ssh into the servers and run the script, the results are placed in the specific user's home directory.For example if user1 & user2 were to run the scrip it would be

```
user1@bar python foo.py
results are placed in /home/user1/results.uniqueID
user2@bar python foo.py
results are placed in /home/user2/results.uniqueID
```

Jenkins executes builds with the user jenkins. The script does work and results are placed in `/var/lib/jenkins/resutls.uniqueID`
But users can't track their own results anymore.

I know I can edit `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` to change the user, but that doesn't account for multiple users at once. Is it possible for Jenkins to launch builds as the user that logged into the Jenkins GUI? Or is possible to have a pre-build script that that can switch the user before `foo.py` is executed?

Comment: Is there any specific requirement to have them all running under different users? After all, it would make the problem much easier to solve if you had a user who's present in all machines/systems. Is it absolutely necessary?

Comment: Yes, it's a requirement the different users is a way for every tester to keep track of which tests they personally ran on which servers. It helps keep everything organized and easily searchable.